# Did any significant source assume a connection with Russia over Germany's anti-nuclear energy frenzy?

Tags: russian-federation, germany, energy-policy

From the perspective of early 2022 it's clear that the anti-nuclear energy frenzy have strengthened the Germany-Russia interdependence that effectively disarms the biggest pressure instrument towards Russia, the potential stop on purchasing gas.

While such interdependence is not necessarily a bad thing - because it makes even limited war extremely costly for both parties, an energetic independence of Europe would be a bad scenario for Russia, which economy is highly dependent on the export of gas and oil.

Have any significant source suggested, that the decision to dismantle the nuclear energy in Germany was influenced by the Russian intelligence? By significant, I mean a serious research institute or media with a big influence (such as nation-wide TV station or newspaper), and not some random celebrity on Quora...

Comment: I haven't done the research to prove a negative, but Fukushima seems to have played a decisive role. Unless you blame Russia for the quake, well ...

Comment: Do you have a source that Germany-Russia gas interdependence actually rose since the implementation of anti-nuclear-policies? According to the german state, the gas consumption since 2000 didn't change significantly (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdgas#Situation_in_Deutschland , source from BMWI ). The gas imports from Russia likewise didn't change significantly (34,7% in 2015 according to the wikipedia article, 32% in 2021 according to https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/how-much-does-germany-need-russian-gas-2022-01-20/). AFAIK the main benefactor is homemade coal and renewables.

Comment: I suggest replacing the very loaded word 'frenzy' with a more neutral one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried searching for old newspaper articles that would suggest such a connection. The idea is certainly not completely out of the blue – but maybe not for the reasons you think. However unfortunately, despite having a potential lead I was unable to locate a full text version of the potential source; and I was unable to locate any articles that might confirm that such a connection was once asssumed. But now, let me explain why the source would have been completely different from what you might have expected.

### History of the decision to no longer use atomic energy in Germany

The origin of the decision to phase out nuclear power predates the large nuclear power accident. Not the one in 2011, the one in 1986.

The 1970's were a turbulent time in German politics with a strong and vocal youth movement. Primary goals of these movements were world peace by demilitarisation, sexual liberties, more democraty, gender equality (especially against discrimination of women), protection of the environment and, already, an anti-nuclear movement. A lot of these movements coalesced into groups that stood for local, later regional and statewide elections. Ultimately, together they formed the new federal Green Party in 1980 to contest national, statewide and local elections under a unified banner.

The main founding myths of this party were equality/equal rights (of men and women), peace and demilitarisation, greater social liberties and democratisation, protection of the environment, and opposing nuclear energy. Some sources (such as Radkau) have argued that the opposition to nuclear energy was a direct consequence of too great a technological optimism in the 1950's and insufficient safety standards, meaning that at least at the time it was scientifically rational. Opposition to nuclear energy and nuclear weapons in all forms, including a complete denuclearisation of Germany has been part of the Green Party's manifesto since day 1.

I don't know what the opinion of the general public on nuclear energy was in the 1960's, 1970's and early 1980's. I do know that Tchernobyl in 1986 was a major event that made national headlines and made sure everybody was at least aware of the (perceived?) dangers of nuclear power. However, even in the 1990's only the Green Party had a clear anti-nuclear manifesto and they not always cleared the 5 % threshold to get elected to parliament so it is safe to say that nuclear power was not the principle decision making factor in people's voting choices.

All that changed in 1998 when the former conservative-liberal coalition government headed by Helmut Kohl lost its majority in the general election. While the social democratic SPD gained the largest number of seats, there was speculation what government would form. Ultimately, it ended up being a red-green coalition composed of SPD and Green Party, headed by chancellor Schröder; the first time the Greens were part of the federal government. The coalition agreement included a clause on the abolishment of nuclear power, and in 2000 an agreement was reached with the electricity supply companies to phase out nuclear power (*Atomausstieg*); the end dates would have been around 2015 to 2020.

This government decision obviously caused the parties to 'pick sides' in a sense. The Greens were, had been and would continue to be anti-nuclear power. The SPD decided to go with the agreement and continue to support it. Neither the liberal FDP nor the conservative CDU/CSU were too fixed on one side of the argument but if pressed, they would likely have been more open to the technology.

One person who was definitely pro-nuclear was physicist and new leader of the CDU, Angela Merkel. The CDU/CSU managed to edge a win out of the 2005 snap election that Schröder had hoped would strengthen his government. Becoming chancellor, Merkel would have preferred to at least extend the lifetimes of the existing nuclear power plants, if not lift the ban altogether. However, the SPD which had just left the government was not keen on rolling its own policies back so the CDU/CSU/SPD government of 2005 did nothing.

In the next scheduled election in 2009, the 'traditional' partners of conservatives and liberals won a majority so they formed a CDU/CSU/FDP government. As part of this coalition agreement, an extension to the exit timeframe was agreed upon and signed into law (*Ausstieg aus dem Ausstieg* or *exit from the exit*). This was protested by civilians and the Green Party obviously voiced their opposition but at a relatively small scale. Then came the earthquake and tsunami of 2011 in Fukushima which caused a surge in anti-nuclear sentiment, probably contributed significantly to the CDU losing the election in the state of Baden-Württemberg – which had been CDU-ruled since the 1950's – to the new Green minister president Kretschmann. The conservative-liberal coalition realised that nuclear energy was now politically dead in Germany and revoked their former decision to extend nuclear power (*Ausstieg aus dem Ausstieg aus dem Ausstieg* or *exit from the exit from the exit*).

So whose fault is, ultimately, the decision to phase out nuclear power? If you will, it was the Green Party from the 1980's, together with civilian protests against various nuclear power projects in the 1970's and 1980's, fuelled by Tchernobyl. Had the Greens not entered government in 1998, things would have been very different and Germany might still not have exited nuclear power – but that is speculation.

### Connections to Russia?

After having cleared up which groups actually are responsible for the exit, we can look at perceived links to Russia. And – it turns out that this wouldn't be extremely tenuous.

The Green Party has always seen itself as left-wing (with a more left (*Fundis* or *fundamentalists*) and a less left (*Realos* or *realists*) wing). Whether or not they are left of the SPD depends on your perspective and the current manifestos of both parties. Arguably, they have a strong overlap across large parts of their left-right spectra and you may see fringes of either party further on either side. This is also true for the predecessor protest groups: World peace, equality and civil liberties are typically seen as left-wing political goals.

(In fact, during the formation of the Green Party, a more conservative fraction did not succeed in getting its policy goals through and decided to leave the party instead forming the ÖDP, (*ökologisch-demokratische Partei* or ecological democratic party) which can be seen as a conservative alternative to the Green Party. For a long time, the major political distinction between the two was the Greens being generally pro-abortion rights while the ÖDP opposes abortion.)

Of course, the 1970's were bang in the middle of the Cold War. Especially conservative forces were very concerned about Russian/Soviet/communist spies or agitators riling up opposition to the democratic state. The fact that the GDR had managed to place a spy (Günther Guillaume) extremely close to chancellor Brandt – who resigned after the story broke. Conservative forces trying to paint anything even remotely left-wing as 'Moscow-led' had been a thing since before the Second World War.

Enter Franz-Josef Strauß, long-time Minister President of Bavaria, long-time leader of the (Bavarian, conservative) CSU, which always considered itself to be a tad more conservative than the CDU. Strauß often spoke at large events and was considered a good rhetor; he is also remembered for very pointed quotes. It is attested that on the CSU's Political Ash Wednesday event in 1985 he said on the Greens and the SPD (first original, then my translation):

> Ihnen geht es um den Umsturz dieses Staates, um eine andere Gesellschafts- und Wirtschaftsordnung.
>
> Their intent is to topple this state, to install a different societal and economic structure.

([German Source](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/franz-josef-strauss-zum-aschermittwoch-die-deftigsten-sprueche-1.300575))

This is dangerously close to stating that the Greens were essentially communist, which in turn would imply that they were communist (i.e. Russian/Soviet) agents. He probably wasn't the only conservative force who thought that but he would probably be the most vocal one. Unfortunately, however, and as stated in the opening paragraph, I was not able to find a *direct* quote of his or an article reporting on such a sentiment that would directly suggest he (or someone else in the CSU) made that connection.

### Okay, that was 1985, what about now?

To contemporary observers of political Germany, two parties stick out as being more Russia-friendly than the others; these parties are the Left Party and the far-right AfD. Some parts of the SPD are also occasionally seen as Russia-friendly, especially those closely connected to former chancellor Schröder (who, famously, is a good friend of Putin's). The Greens, FDP and CDU/CSU are generally not suspected of having any close relationship with Russia or being susceptible to Russian influence.

Ironically, the only relevant party currently arguing in favour of nuclear energy is the AfD.

The decision to phase out nuclear power predates Putin's ascent to President of Russia as stated above. And, as stated, in general nuclear power is seen as politically dead.

So while it is hard proving a negative, I would wager that no significant source has suggested any Russian influence in the exit decision – or on the primary actor, the Green Party – since the fall of the Soviet Union.

Comment: If you go back far enough, 1983, the advantages of an [anti-nuclear movement](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1983/10/23/more-than-a-million-protest-missiles-in-western-europe/9d703245-36fa-40ce-8714-e281f796a472/), re. nuclear weapons, would have been evident to the USSR:  *Despite his eloquent plea against new missiles, Brandt was criticized harshly by Greens Party leaders for failing to denounce all weapons systems and for not demanding West Germany's withdrawal from the North Atlantic Treaty Organization.*  However, by now, it's a stretch to see Russian meddling.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that nowadays the Greens are the more "Atlanticist" ones, compared to CDU and SPD?

Comment: I fully agree with this. I know people who protested nuclear energy as far back as the 1970s, who at the time also happened to be members of (one of the many) communist party(s), but there was no relation between those two things. Their opposition to nuclear energy was based on safety and environmental reasons as well as concerns about dual-use. And at least in some aspects, they were right: for example, at least in my country, after 62 years, we are not a single step closer to figuring out how to deal with the spent fuel and other waste than we were in 1960 when the first plant went online.

Comment: @PeteW I'm not sure. The Greens today definitely have a way stronger "Atlanticist" tendency than they did 30 years ago, but most of that is better classified as catch-up. In addition, while *some* of the people in the party leadership are very "Atlanticist", significant chunks of the rank-and-file members are still much more anti-"Atlanticist", because they equate "Atlanticism" with Nato which they equate with war-waging. Meanwhile, while the CDU certainly struggled with Trump, by and large in my impression they are still very "Atlanticist". The SPD I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any significant source that has made such claim.
But given that Russia is being blamed for a wide variety of undesired outcomes (even - and sometimes especially by - serious sources), I would be surprised if no significant source has ever attempted to link Russia to Germany's nuclear energy exit.
Having lived in Germany for a while during and right after Chernobyl, I can attest that the popular movement against nuclear energy truly started at that point, and got larger with every nuclear incident.
Thus, yes it can certainly be stated that there is a Russian (or rather Soviet Union) link but I guess it is not the one referred to here (Chernobyl was in the Soviet Union).